# Why does the Java compiler not let me return a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I'm a bit at a loss with generics. I have the following code:

```
public interface SampleValue<T> {
    T getValue();
}

public static class SampleBoolean implements SampleValue<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue() {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}

public static final class SampleValueGenerator {
    private SampleValueGenerator() {
        // do not call
    }

    public static <T, R extends SampleValue<T>> R forType(Class<T> clazz) {
        if(Boolean.class.equals(clazz)) {
            return new SampleBoolean();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try this, IntelliJ (i.e. the compiler) tells me that `R` and `SampleBoolean` are incompatible types (for the `return` line).

When I try the non-generic (raw) return type

`public static <T> SampleValue forType(Class<T> clazz) {`

I don't get any error;

`public static <T, R extends SampleValue<?>> R forType(Class<T> clazz) {`

(with the `?` wildcard) however fails again. And for

`public static <T> SampleValue<T> forType(Class<T> clazz) {`

I get `Incompatible types, Found: SampleBoolean, Required: SampleValue<T>`.

My guess is that it has to do with e.g. List not being an ancestor of List (but a sibling), but I fail to see the wood for the trees with the above.

Can someone please explain what's going on, and why the long example doesn't work?

Update: NB: The idea was to have a few more if/else branches for different types, but I stopped when the compiler started complaining...

Comment: The example code can be foiled by declaring a `class AnotherSampleBoolean implements SampleValue<Boolean> {...}` and then calling `AnotherSampleBoolean result = forType(Boolean.class)`. `R` would be inferred as `AnotherSampleBoolean` and at runtime it would throw `ClassCastException` casting `SampleBoolean` to `AnotherSampleBoolean`. So, if you were going to do something like this with e.g. unchecked casting to get past the compiler error, the declaration `<T> SampleValue<T> forType(Class<T>)` is the most stable.

Comment: @Radiodef that makes sort of sense, but `<T> SampleValue<T> forType(Class<T>)` fails, too...

Comment: `public static <T> SampleValue<?> forType(Class<T> clazz) {` (with wildcard, non-generic return type) works...

Comment: To get past the compiler error, you would need to use unchecked casting, like `return (SomeValue<T>) new SampleBoolean();`. Mapping 1:1 `Class<T>` to `SomeOtherType<T>` is one of the few cases where unchecked casting is a reasonable idea. If you were mapping `Class<T>` to `T` then you could use `return clazz.cast(result)`, but there's no way to do that for a `SomeOtherType<T>`. I don't think I'd really *recommend* unchecked casting, though, unless you understand why it's necessary/why it works/why it's probably safe here. Unchecked casts can be hard to debug if you do something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your conditional doesn't prove anything to the compiler.

The confusion you're having here involves your conditional:

```
if(Boolean.class.equals(clazz))
```

With this check, you're inferring that `T` is a `Boolean`, but the compiler has no way of enforcing this. The compiler doesn't implicitly assume that this check will ensure `T` is `Boolean`. (All the compiler knows about `equals` in the context of this method is that it returns a `boolean`.)

Therefore, despite your check, `R` and `SampleBoolean` are incompatible types because `R extends SampleValue<T>` while `T` can be anything at all.

I can't really come up with a way to ensure a return of `new SampleValue<T>` based on `T` but if I do I will edit this answer with a solution. I'd love to see ideas from others about it.

Comment: his interface is a functional interface, probably could use lambdas and then create a type T through reflection using clazz.newInstance(), the only drawback is that if there is no default constructor and exception needs to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `SampleBoolean` implements `SampleValue<Boolean>` which is a specific type and not something generic. On the other hand, R is declared to extend a generic type `SampleValue<T>`.

`SampleValue<T>` and `SampleValue<Boolean>` are two different types, so this is why you get that compilation error. The `forType` function wants to return a generic type R and you return a specific type with the following statement:

```
return new SampleBoolean();
```

Answer (score 0):

The R you are returning is always an R that implements SampleValue of Boolean  and not an R that implements SampleValue of T (generic type that is set in runtime).

```
// if i do this
SampleValueGenerator.forType(Integer.class) 
// i am expecting something that implements SampleValue<Integer>
// but you are always returning something that implements SampleValue<Boolean>
```

**EDIT** This should work (did not test yet)

```
public static <T, R extends SampleValue<T>> R forType(Class<T> clazz) {
    return () -> {
        try{
            return (T)clazz.newInstance(); // Also clazz should have a default constructor.
        }catch(Excepetion e){
            // This catch block should be for NoSuchMethodException and InstantionException
        }
    }
}
```